# what exactily is this Global Objective?

Tags: scorm2004

what is the difference between this primary-objective & global-objectives
everyone is telling about the global objective and there is no clear definition of this global objective.

please clarify this global objective .

Answer (score 0):

In SCORM, there are two types of objectives (local objectives and shared global objectives). Please check the following links to get your answer:

http://support.scorm.com/entries/96011-what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-objective-and-a-shared-global-objective

http://support.scorm.com/entries/67062-identifying-a-global-objective-vs-a-local-objective